# Insert Opportunity, Quote, QuotelineItem, Asset in single upload using data loader

Tags: data-loader, dataloader.io, loader

I have exported csv file of Opportunity, Quote, QuoteLineItem, Asset(Quote Line) from external system and want to insert one by one in salesforce.

but the thing is these four are related with eachother, see following,

```
    > Opportunity - (Parent)
        > Quote - (Child of Opportunity)
            > QuoteLineItem - (Child of Quote)
                > Asset(Quote Line) - (Child of QuoteLineItem)
```

How can i insert these all four in a single upload using data loader ?

please suggest !!

Comment: They is no way to upload data in single shot by using data loader, you need to go like parent-->child process only.

Comment: the smart solution is to use external ids for each object so you can do 4 data loader uploads without having to copy IDs from the Opportunity into the Quote.csv

Comment: @cropredy yes. thank you !! i should try this solution OR i am thinking that let me write one apex trigger on before insert to get match with record name.

Comment: The trigger will also work.  Suggest you tie it to a specific running Data Migration user.